# How to map an Array of JSON to Array of class instances, whose constructor takes a JSON as argument in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, constructor, casting

Lets say I have a class in TypeScript:

```
class A{
    a:number;
    b:number;

    constructor(data:object){
        this.a = data.some_name_for_a
        this.b = data.something_else
    }
```

and also an object[]:

```
list_of_data = [
                {some_name_for_a:5, something_else:1, c:7},
                {some_name_for_a:6, something_else:4, c:1},
                {some_name_for_a:3, something_else:3, c:3}
               ]
```

How do I get an array A[]? I need something like:

```
list_of_data.map(A.constructor)
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: Do you require this to be point free? It's possible but it's easier to either define a factory method or to just do a `list.map(data =>new A(data))`

Comment: Nope, this is perfectly fine. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.